# Як правильно "боді" чи "бодік"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Стаття Вікепедії ***"[Боді](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96)"*** - вид обтягуючого одягу, що закриває тулуб.

В СУМ-20 присутне визначення

> ***[БОДІ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=197331&page=186)*** *невідм., с.* Жіноча або дитяча облягаюча білизна. *Боді – одна із найнеобхідніших речей у гардеробі немовляти, річ, у яку майже постійно малюк вдягнений вдома* (із журн.).

На Словотвір зовсім інше визначення слова ***"боді"***

> ***[БОДІ](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bodi)*** - базовий модуль фотоапарата без об'єктива та інших
>   пристосувань.
>   В значені одягу пропонують інше визначення
>
> ***[БОДІК](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bodik)*** - елемент дитячого одягу, який малята носять від
>   народження. Бодік або боді виглядає як закритий купальник. Зверху
>   бодік може мати довгі або короткі рукава, а також просто брителі.

В інших словниках ні *"боді"*, ні *"бодік"* не знайшла.

Яке слово правильно (літературно) вживати в значенні елементу одягу? Чи можемо вживати обидва слова як взаємозамінні?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Якщо довіряти «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах (хоча він зустрічає певну критику й не всі довіряють йому на 100%), то слово ***бо́ді*** у відповідному значенні («жіноча або дитяча облягаюча білизна») вже є **нормативним**.

Щодо ***бо́дік***, то з Вашого ж запитання слідує, що це слово досі ніде **не зафіксоване**. Як правильно зазначив follower (у вилученому пізніше коментарі), загалом, мабуть, мало б бути *бо́дик*. Тільки на мою думку, тут справа не в правилі дев'ятки, а в тому, що щонайменше для основ на *-д* в українській мові традиційно застосовується *-ик-*: *ведме́дик*, *молоди́к*, *парохо́дик*. (Мені *-ік* підсвідомо здається схожим на росіянізм. Хоча в якійсь телепередачі про еволюцію української мови казали, що в українській мові теж колись було *ко́тік*, *бра́тік* тощо — не перевіряв, наскільки це правда — але в будь-якому разі, мова змінюється, і колись, можливо, *-ік* знов чи не знов стане прийнятним для нас, але зараз поширенішим здається *-ик*.)